# With tens of thousands of upstream users and frequent changes, what are the problems with the current implementation of Apache APISIX How to solve it?

Tags: apache-apisix

If I have tens of thousands of upstream now and it's changing a lot, how can I use Apisix to better solve this, are there any best practices？

Answer (score 0):

Since there are so many upstreams, updates to those will cause high CPU usage as they need to be updated in the etcd cluster. Moreover, inside the etcd cluster, there should be a quorum status for consistency in case of database writes which will also increase etcd CPU usage.

To improve this situation we can refer upstreams using upstream id when creating routes so that the load is lesser as no need to update route configuration.